# TikZ - foreach substitution inside coordinate name not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, coordinates

I have coordinates named `a1` to `a9`.
They were defined by `\coordinate (a1) at (0,0);` etc.
They all have valid x and y coordinates.
I need to create 9 circles whose centers are each of the 9 coordinates and have a radius of 1.
Instead of manualy going through all of them, I decided to use a `foreach` loop.

```
\foreach \i in {1,..,9} {
    \draw (a\i) circle [radius=1];
}
```

However I get `No shape named 'a' is known` error.

```
\foreach \i in {1,..,9} {
    \draw (a{\i}) circle [radius=1];
}
```

Even if I add curly braces I still get `No shape named 'a{1}' is known` error.
What is the correct syntax to achieve what I want?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!! We need a MWE to see what happens. That said, the syntax in the `\foreach` loops requires 3 dots: `\foreach \i in {1,...,9}`

Comment: As @JuanCastaño said, the `..` are taken literal and TikZ tries `(a..)` which it interprets as node `a` and anchor `.` and if you don't have a node/coordinate named `a` you get the error. The `{}` wouldn't help anyway as they are taken literal (as you can see from the error message).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you misspelled the nodes?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % defines nodes directly or within a loop
    \node (a1) at (0, 0) {$a0$};
    \foreach \x in {2,...,9}{
      \coordinate (a\x) at (\x, 0);
    }
    % draws the circles
    \foreach \i in {1,...,9} {
      \draw (a\i) circle [radius=1];
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oups, I labelled `a0` instead of `a1`…